# I am using the GUI and my daemon doesn't start anymore

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I've been using the GUI for some time and suddenly the daemon doesn't start anymore. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, this is likely caused by your blockchain being corrupt. A blockchain can corrupt if you shut down the daemon ungracefully (e.g. a hard shut down or your PC going into sleep mode while you were syncing). As a general piece of advice, if you need to shut down your PC, first shut down `monerod` gracefully by typing `exit` (if you're running `monerod` separately) or click on the `x` (right top) if you're running `monerod` from within the GUI. Otherwise, you might corrupt the blockchain and you'd have to start all over again.

Now, let's verify that your blockchain is really corrupt so that you don't unnecessarily have to start all over again. This is done as follows.

**[1]** Exit the GUI.

**[2]** Browse to the directory `monerod` is located. On Windows and Linux this is the same directory as `monero-wallet-gui`, whereas on Mac OS X `monerod` is located in `~/Applications/monero-wallet-gui.app/Contents/MacOS` | Note that if you cannot find `monerod`, it could be that your AV (AntiVirus) has quarantined it. In case this occurred, I'd advise to either put it back in the original folder / directory and create an exception or re-extract the binaries (the `.zip` file (Windows) or the `tar.bz2` file (Mac OS X and Linux)) to a new folder / directory (for which an exception is created).

**[3]** Open `monerod` manually by double clicking on it (Windows and Mac OS X) or from the terminal with `./monerod` (Linux).

**[4]** It'll likely shut down itself quickly. If that happens, proceed with the guide.

**[5]** If it doesn't shut down itself, type `status` a few times to check whether it's fetching any new blocks. If it isn't, proceed with the guide. It it fetches new blocks, however, it's not corrupted and the GUI was simply unable to start the daemon. Try restarting `monero-wallet-gui`. It should automatically connect to the daemon that's already running.

**[6]** Browse to `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero` (Windows) or `~/.bitmonero` (Linux and Mac OS X).

**[7]** Note that, by default, both `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero` and `~/.bitmonero` are hidden directories.

**[8a]** On Windows, you have to use the explorer to manually navigate to `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero`

**[8b]** On Mac OS X, you can typically use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to unhide directories.

**[8c]** On Linux, you can typically use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide directories.

**[9]** Now open `bitmonero.log`

**[10]** If your log contains this line or something similar, the blockchain is corrupted:

> `Failed to query m_blocks: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid`

**[11]** We'll first attempt to fix this before performing a resync from scratch.

**[12]** Again browse to the directory `monerod` is located.

**[13a]** On Windows, open a new command prompt from the same directory as `monerod.exe`. This is done by first making sure your cursor isn't located on any of the files and subsequently doing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>right click</kbd>. It will give you an option to "Open command window here". If you're using Windows 10, it'll, most likely, give you an option to open the Powershell.

**[13b]** On Linux and Mac OS X, open a new terminal from the same directory as `monerod`

**[14a]** On Windows, type the following command in the command prompt:

`monerod.exe --db-salvage`

If that doesn't work in the Powershell, type:

`.\monerod.exe --db-salvage`

If that doesn't work either in the Powershell, type:

`./monerod.exe --db-salvage`

If that doesn't work either in the Powershell, type:

`./monerod --db-salvage`

**[14b]** On Linux and Mac OS X, type the following command in the terminal:

`./monerod --db-salvage`

**[15]** If you were using a non-default directory for the blockchain, you have to add the `--data-dir` flag too if you start `monerod` separately. If you already have `monerod` running, type `exit` first to gracefully stop the daemon. This is done as follows:

On Windows, type the following command in the command prompt:

`monerod.exe --db-salvage --data-dir path\to\your\blockchain`

If that doesn't work in the Powershell, type:

`.\monerod.exe --db-salvage --data-dir path\to\your\blockchain`

If that doesn't work either in the Powershell, type:

`./monerod.exe --db-salvage --data-dir path\to\your\blockchain`

On Linux and Mac OS X, type the following command in the terminal:

`./monerod --db-salvage --data-dir path/to/your/blockchain`

**[16]** If that doesn't work you, unfortunately, have to resync from scratch. This is done by deleting `data.mdb` from `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero` or `~/.bitmonero` (Linux and Mac OS X), which will trigger the resync.

Comment: Thank you for posting the assistance. However, I cannot locate `.bitmonero` on my OSX. (I realize it is a hidden file)

Comment: Have you tried using `CMD+SHIFT+DOT` to unhide directories?

Comment: Oh. Derp. I thought spotlight search would search hidden files but I just found it with Bash...Thanks

Comment: The .log file does not contain `Failed to query m_blocks: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid`, should I first follow the directions to fix that or just do a resync? After a resync will coins still be available which were sent to this address?

Comment: What happens if you run `monerod` manually? Also, a resync from scratch will not affect your wallet balance.

Comment: ```WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received
daemon update is needed now.
WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received
monerod*** error incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: And thereafter the application closes I presume?

Comment: I've followed these instructions all the way to [15]. But now I'm seeing "Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1 -> 1538060 [Your node is 1538059 blocks (1434 days) behind."  So it's basically having to sync all the way from the first block again? This is going to take forever. Would I just be better off deleting data.mdb and starting all over again?

Comment: @StrawbsUK - Did you accidentally delete the blockchain? "Would I just be better off deleting data.mdb and starting all over again?" <= Probably, yes.

Comment: No, I haven't deleted the blockchain. I still have a 51.59GB data.mdb file but after following the above instructions to [15] it started syncing from block 1. Surely this shouldn't be necessary?

Comment: @StrawbsUK - Are you using a custom data directory?

Comment: No, default directory.  On Mac OS: user/.bitmonero/lmdb/data.mdb

Comment: That is odd. Are you running `monerod` separately / manually? If so, could you check where it loads the blockchain from? Also, the ~51 GB data file is in `~/.bitmonero/lmdb` right?

Comment: 130GB of data down the drain... It is very unfortunate that it can not use the 99.9% of data that isn't corrupted. In my case the file was extended but it contains \x00s at the end, as the data was not fsynced.

Comment: @AndreiDamian-Fekete - Did you try to salvage the blockchain file with the `--db-salvage` flag?

Comment: @dEBRUYNE, yes, it didn't work. Maybe these corruptions don't happen very often, but it would be super helpful to have some "checkpoints" in the file, not to start from the beginning with the download and checks if the data gets corrupted when appending to it.

Comment: A more simple option is to simply add the `--db-sync-mode=safe` startup flag, which will make the blockchain file robust against corruption (though it will slow down the sync).

Answer (score 1):

Also recently, Comodo and various other firewalls have added a Secret option to Block Loopback Traffic / Filter Loopback Traffic (127.x.x.x)
This is  "SEPARATE option"  from the application / Firewall rules.

That means, even if you approved Monerod.exe and the GUI FULL INTERNET ACCESS on your firewall rules , firewalls will Still Block them talking to each other.

This drives 'a wall' between your GUI and the Daemon.  So even if both START  can connect to the internet,
you still get the 'Cannot start daemon' or  'Cannot connect to Daemon' error  (ie; they cannot talk to each other)

To solve this, go to your firewall and **Look for any settings option which mentions "127"....... or "Loopback".** Don't just look on the rules page, this option is often location on a different settings page.

If you find any mention of Loopback traffic and 127.x.x.x , Try enabling and permitting it, since the monero daemon uses this, that will remove the wall between the Daemon and the GUI

Hope this helps someone.