# Why has my Monero daemon failed to start?

Tags: monerod, daemon, macos, connection, issue

I successfully started my daemon several months ago using **v12** and I haven't used the **Monero GUI Wallet** since. I just upgraded to **v13** and I still can't get it to start.

Following the instructions at [this link](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6825/i-am-using-the-gui-and-my-daemon-doesnt-start-anymore#comment6580_6826), I can't find the `.bitmonero` folder to diagnose the issue.

When I run the `monerod` application, I see this:

```
2019-01-10 03:52:26.687   0x7fff769e3000    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:287 Monero 'Beryllium Bullet' (v0.13.0.4-release)
2019-01-10 03:52:26.687   0x7fff769e3000    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:53    Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2019-01-10 03:52:26.687   0x7fff769e3000    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:58    Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2019-01-10 03:52:26.688   0x7fff769e3000    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:63 Initializing p2p server...
2019-01-10 03:52:28.469   0x7fff769e3000    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:68 p2p server initialized OK
2019-01-10 03:52:28.470   0x7fff769e3000    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:63 Initializing core RPC server...
2019-01-10 03:52:28.470   0x7fff769e3000    INFO    global  contrib/epee/include/net/http_server_impl_base.h:76 Binding on 127.0.0.1:18081
2019-01-10 03:52:28.470   0x7fff769e3000    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:69 core RPC server initialized OK on port: 18081
2019-01-10 03:52:28.471   0x7fff769e3000    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:86    Initializing core...
2019-01-10 03:52:28.471   0x7fff769e3000    INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:447 Loading blockchain from folder /Users/myusername/.bitmonero/lmdb ...
2019-01-10 03:52:28.472   0x7fff769e3000    INFO    global  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:4071 Migrating blockchain from DB version 1 to 2 - this may take a while:
2019-01-10 03:52:28.473   0x7fff769e3000    ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:185    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2019-01-10 03:52:28.473   0x7fff769e3000    WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:75   Failed to parse tx from blob retrieved from the db
2019-01-10 03:52:28.473   0x7fff769e3000    ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:548 Error opening database: Failed to parse tx from blob retrieved from the db
2019-01-10 03:52:28.576   0x7fff769e3000    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:96 Deinitializing core RPC server...
2019-01-10 03:52:28.576   0x7fff769e3000    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:90 Deinitializing p2p...
2019-01-10 03:52:29.704   0x7fff769e3000    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:103   Deinitializing core...
2019-01-10 03:52:29.704   0x7fff769e3000    ERROR   daemon  src/daemon/core.h:108   Failed to deinitialize core...
2019-01-10 03:52:29.704   0x7fff769e3000    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:75    Stopping cryptonote protocol...
2019-01-10 03:52:29.704   0x7fff769e3000    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:79    Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
```

How do I get this sorted out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On your system it's -> `/Users/myusername/.bitmonero/lmdb` | Note that, by default, this directory is hidden. You can, on Mac OS X, typically use `CMD + SHIFT + DOT` to unhide directories.

Comment: Thanks. Found that and when opening .bitmonero I see several lines that seem concerning. 

Example:  2019-01-10 15:40:59.024  0x7fff769e3000 INFO logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:277 New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO

Do I proceed with step [15] on these instructions? If so, what’s generally the path to the blockchain?

Comment: The `--db-salvage` flag is typically unsuccessful. I'd personally suggest to skip it and perform step 16. In case you do feel like trying it, on your system the path is `/Users/myusername/.bitmonero` , where `myusername` probably is your real name (you can check on your system). Let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: That took ages but did the trick. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Good to hear you managed to resolve your issue :)