# How to purge Monero GUI

Tags: monerod

Today I downloaded the latest version of Monero GUI, extracted it in my directory /path/to/gui and executed the GUI client. Now I created a wallet and automatically the monero daemon started. Howerver, a minute later my computer chrashed. 10 minutes later I just rebooted. This was my mistake since I had other programs running which consumed all CPU at the time. I did not expect the daemon to be that demanding in power.

Now trying to restart the process (deleting everything, downloading the gui, creating a new wallet, etc.) I only get to the point of this error "cannot conntect to demon ..." check your log etc. The log as such only records "cannot conntect to ...". Creating wallets is no issue.

To cut it short I deleting everything also my wallet etc. does not help at all. A fresh start still brings me the connecting error.

I would like to use monero on the same machine. How do I purge everything for me to get a fresh start? How do I unblock the port for the daemon?

This does not help since I already deleted everything:
[I am using the GUI and my daemon doesn't start anymore](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6825/i-am-using-the-gui-and-my-daemon-doesnt-start-anymore)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, you did delete the `data.mdb` file? Because a corrupt file would cause that error. Note that it is typically located in a hidden directory.

Comment: No I did not. Located a file at /home/me/.bitmonero/lmdb/data.mdb and /home/me/.shared-ringdb/data.mdb. I will kill these two and try again prior to going to bed tonight.

Comment: That should resolve your issue. If not, please let me know.